# Java HashMap size allocated

Tags: java, hashmap

Java Hash Map has a size() method, 
which reflects how many elements are set int the Hash Map.
I am interested to know what is the actual size of the Hash Map.
I tried different methods but can't find the correct one.
I set the initial Capacity to 16

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap(16);
    for(int i=0;i<100;++i){
        System.out.println(hm.size());
        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        hm.pet(uuid ,null);

    }
```

when i will add values this size can increase, how can i check the size that is actually allocated?

Answer (score 3):

> what is the actual size of the Hash Map

I'm assuming you are asking about the capacity. The capacity is the length of the array holding the buckets of the `HashMap`s. The initial capacity is 16 by default.

The `capacity` method is not public, but you can calculate the current capacity based on the current `size`, the initial capacity and the load factor.

If you use the defaults (for example, when you create the `HashMap` with the parameter-less constructor), the initial capacity is 16, and the default load factor is 0.75. This means the capacity will be doubled to 32 once the size reaches 16 * 0.75 == 12. It will be doubled to 64 once the size reaches 32 * 0.75 == 24.

If you pass different initial capacity and/or load factor to the constructor, the calculation will be affected accordingly.

Comment: why it doubles from 32 to 64?
i though it increase in steps of 16.
also how can i simulate to see that data goes into 1 element in the init array, and maybe even to see the Tree that is build for this slot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Reflection` to check actual allocated size *(bucket size)* of the map.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("Abhi", 101);
m.put("John", 102);

System.out.println(m.size());   // This will print 2

Field tableField = HashMap.class.getDeclaredField("table");
tableField.setAccessible(true);
Object[] table = (Object[]) tableField.get(m);

System.out.println(table.length);  // This will print 16
```

Comment: Is there a way to know how many buckets were really used and what the size of each one of them?